# Azure DevOps YAML - Restore Multiple Projects Manually

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure DevOps with .Net Core Restore, but specifying multiple projects (line by line like in VSTS) outputs "No files matched the search pattern.".

If there is only one project it works, how can i do this with multiple projects?

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  name: "ProvisionRestoreProjects"
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'    
    projects: '**/ProjectA.csproj
**/ProjectB.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'MyFeedArtifact-master'
    arguments: '--configuration release  --no-cache'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can specify multiple projects in this way:

```
- task DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    commands: restore
    projects: |
     **/ProjectA.csproj
     **/ProjectB.csproj
    vstsFeed: 'my-feed'
```

I guess you used the Tasks helper and you got the yaml generated, but I think there is a bug there.

Comment: For some reason passing projects in pack seems to pick extra projects, do you have any idea why?

Comment: created a post with the question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949459/azure-devops-yaml-dotnet-core-cli-pack-builds-additional-projects

Comment: In case someone still gets the "No files matched the search pattern" error, make sure that you do _not_ include quotation marks after `|` in your project paths. For a single project, I had `projects: '**/ProjectA.csproj'`, and then I simply added the `|` and put the `'**/ProjectA.csproj'` on a new line. In YAML, this however means that the quotes are included, so the project path would now start with `'` (which is, of course, invalid).